# How to launch app with arguments on Windows?

Tags: windows, arguments, launching-application

I would like launch an installed app on Windows and pass a string to it, so it can load a text and image directly after it started.

I imagine something like this:

```
C:\MyApp\example.exe?share&text=helloworld&img=example.jpg
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It would help if you specified a language. Otherwise, assuming raw Windows APIs, look into [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I don't know where to start, what ways are available and how this is usually done.

Comment: That *all* depends on your language of choice. I gave you the WinAPI links because those tend to be a sort of lowest common denominator that most languages can access and use. Anything fancier will be on a language-by-language basis.